# javascript Onclick other frameset

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, frame, frameset

sorry for my english, 
i'm js newbie

PLS HELP
i have site with a frameset. left, top, and main
and i want to add chat with other userlist in the left frame.

but when i click those userlist, the chatbox show in the left frame, not the main frame..
this is the code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="javascript:chatWith('$username')">Chat With $username</a>
```

i've add line like this but not working :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="top.frames['mainFrame'].location='welcome.php' ;javascript:chatWith('$username')">Chat With $username</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="top.frames['mainFrame'].location='welcome.php' ;javascript:chatWith('$username')">Chat With $username</a>
```

replace $username to `<?php $username ?>`

Comment: thanks phantu..the script is fine..but,
the question is my chatbox show up in the left frame, not main frame..
how can i move the chatbox to the mainFrame, because the leftframe only have some space

Comment: Have you use **target** tag of HTML